# HTML/CSS: How to avoid inheriting styles from parent class (using react-select with bootstrap)

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-select

I am facing a styling issue when trying to use react-select with bootstrap css.

*This **maybe** a generic issue which has nothing to do with these libraries. I am not 100% sure.*

Here is a codesandbox demo to show the issue I am facing.
https://codesandbox.io/s/k0325onrk3

The issue, as I can understand, is that the child element `div class="Select-control"` is inheriting styles from the parent class(`form-control`).

**Edit:**
One option here would be to override the styles by my self, one by one. But I feel that's hard and not scalable. I do have noticed elements inheriting styles given the cascading nature of CSS, but this is the first time I am seeing an element inheriting a whole class of CSS from the parent. Am I missing something here?

**Edit 2(Answer):** Turns out, the issue was not with inheriting the class from the parent. The weird behaviour was due to react-select introducing a new `select` like element. Basically, `form-control` class in bootstrap assumes its child to be text (or something without styles like borders) and hence adds a padding. But the actual child introduced by react-select is another element which has similar styles to `form-control`. Thus the child shows this weird behaviour. So the solution is to override the styles in `form-control` class and not in the child(Which I assumed at first).

I can see the following when I inspect that element with chrome.

[image]

How do I prevent the `div class="Select-control"` element from inheriting styles from `form-control` class of the parent element?

Comment: only the 3 properties (darker red) are inherited you cant prevent this afaik, you have to override them if you want a different font-size for example.

Comment: override those by your self :`select-control{    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.5;}`

Comment: you cannot avoid inheritance - css always cascades (kind of given away by the name), the only thing you can do is overwrite the style you do not want to inherit

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you, I just renamed the class to "form-control-new", you can add your custom name. Attached image for reference.

you can write your custom css on the new class name.

[class-rename-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c7e4.png)